# Homotopy type theory: what is «path induction» useful for?

Tags: homotopy-theory, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I am reading the [HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/). At page 49 *path induction* is introduced. Let us recap it.

Given a family

$$ C: \displaystyle \prod_{(x,y:A)}   x =_A y \rightarrow  $$

and a function

$$ c: \displaystyle \prod_{x:A} C(x,x,refl_x) $$

then — by *path induction* — we have a function $f$

$$ f: \displaystyle \prod_{(x,y:A)} \prod_{p:x=_Ay}  C(x,y,p) $$

such that

$$ f(x,x,refl_x) ≡: c(x) $$

---

But I think I can derive $f$ *without* path induction:

- since $C$ is a *type family*, I can get $f$ from *dependent function formation rule*:

  $$ f: \displaystyle \prod_{(x,y:A)} \prod_{p:x=_Ay}  C(x,y,p) $$
- And if I apply $f$ to $(x,x,refl_x)$ I get $C(x,x,refl_x)$, which is $c$.

---

If I were correct, «path induction» would be redundant. So what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure where the dependent function formation rule comes from. It clearly doesn't always exist, since $C(x, y, p)$ could just be the empty type. Also note that $c$ is chosen beforehand. You can't just decide afterwards that $f(x, x, refl_x)$ is the $c$ you started with without path induction.

Comment: Your f(x,x,refl_x) and c(x) have the same type C(x,x,refl_x), but they are not definitionally equal: the value of your f(x,x,refl_x) remains undefined, only its type is known.

Comment: One possibility for your confusion - I haven't seen the phrase *dependent function formation rule* used elsewhere, but I'd expect it to say that $\prod_{(x,y:A)} \prod_{p:x=_Ay}  C(x,y,p)$ is a type, not that it has an inhabitant. That's typically what "formation rules" are.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to instantiate/derive some inhabitant of $C$ is through the hypothesis (i.e. function inputs) or with some axiom (i.e. introduction rule) that can also be thought of as context inputs.

Since C have no constructors in the standard HoTT axioms, it has to be built from the inputs. Specifically we have $C, c, x, y, p$ as inputs but only $c$ can construct some inhabitant of $C$. Unfortunately the specific type that $c$ returns is not equal to the required one (i.e. $C(x,x,refl_x) \neq C(x,y,p)$) and as a consequence $f$ cannot be derived since we cannot return an inhabitant of $C(x,y,p)$.

I am almost sure that neither can a negation of the path induction be derived, and that is why it is an axiom/rule of HoTT.